# My sums won't appear correctly

Tags: java

just learning Java for the first time and I can't figure out why my sums won't show correctly from the user's input.. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    System.out.println("Enter an income (Any negative number to quit):"); 
    ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sum = 0.0;
    double avg = 0.0;

    while (true)
    { 
    double number = one.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter an income (Any negative number to quit):");
    if (number >= 0)        
    { 
    numbers.add(number);   

    }

    else{ 
        double min = Collections.min(numbers);
        double max = Collections.max(numbers);

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        {
        i = numbers.size();
        sum = sum + i;  
        }
         avg = sum / numbers.size();        
        double value = 0.0;                     
        System.out.println("The minimum number is " + min);
        System.out.println("The maximum number is " + max);
        System.out.println("Sum " + sum); //
        System.out.println("The Average number is " + avg); 
    }



    }
```

Comment: *"won't show correctly"* - what would be *correct*? What happens instead?

Comment: please provide given input and Output you get

Comment: Not sure if this is the error but you shouldn't change `i` inside the body of your loop. Basically your current code starts at `i = 0` then immediately sets `i` to the size of the collection and adds that to `sum`. The loop would then end since `i` now isn't lower than the size of the collection anymore.

Comment: You should learn how to debug java code in your favourite Java IDE

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are the problem:

```
i = numbers.size();
sum = sum + i;
```

You should never change the loop variable inside the loop. What happens when you do this is the loop ends early, and not every value of `i` is added to the sum.

You also don't want to add `i` to the sum... You want to add the element at the `i`th position.

You should just do something like:

```
for (Double num : numbers) {
    sum = sum + num;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I knew it had to be something with those two lines.

Comment: @KevN. No problem. If this solved the issue please upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You override the index `i` to array size so you enter once to the loop and set the array size in `sum`, instead you can do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
{
    sum = sum + numbers.get(i);  
}
```

You can also use foreach:

```
for (Double number : numbers)
{
    sum = sum + number;
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much, I knew it had to be something with those two lines as I kept changing them over and over!

Comment: @KevN. remember to accept (and possibly upvote) his answer.